# Does PowerShell require the opening curly brace of a script block to be on the same line?

Tags: powershell, syntax

Okay, the expected "output" of this script is fairly obvious, and it works.  It copies files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    if ($_.Name.ToUpper().Contains("INCLUDE_PUBLIC")){
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Include "*.h" -Path $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item ($_.FullName) ("e:\IncTest")}
    }
}
```

However, if I move the opening brace `{` to the next line, I get the following output:

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:
```

Am I getting tricked by some other syntax issue, or does ForEach-Object require its brace to be on the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PS C:\> Get-Help -Name 'ForEach-Object'

SYNTAX
    ForEach-Object [-MemberName] <String> [-ArgumentList <Object[]>] [-Confirm] [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]

    ForEach-Object [-Process] <ScriptBlock[]> [-Begin <ScriptBlock>] [-Confirm] [-End <ScriptBlock>] [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-RemainingScripts <ScriptBlock[]>] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

By using a script block, you're using positionally-bound parameters of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.  In this case, the `-Process { }` parameter set.  If you escape the end of the line (in essence, escaping the newline), you can get around that, but it's generally a bad practice.

Comment: Ohhhhh.  This is really helpful, and I just learned a couple of things about reading powershell documentation as well.  Thank you, sir!

Comment: nm.  I think I mostly understand that I don't know how to read powershell documentation and probably should painfully read the documentation on the documentation.  But I also understand the gist of your answer :)

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell has **two distinct parsing modes**, owing to the fact that it is both a *shell* and a *scripting language*.

- ***Argument* mode** is line-oriented and is **shell-like**: It applies to a single command invoking an executable / script / cmdlet / alias / function, or a series of such commands chained with the pipe symbol (`|`) to form a pipeline.

  - **Each individual command must be *on its own line*** and the only way to spread it across multiple lines is to use *line continuation*, which requires escaping the very end of each interior line with `` ` `` (a backtick).
    However, that practice is both visually subtle and brittle (placing even just spaces or tabs after the `` ` `` breaks the command).
  - In order to spread the individual commands of a *pipeline* across multiple lines (without having to use line continuation), end each line but the last with `|`.
- ***Expression* mode** works **as it does in other programming languages** in which whitespace isn't significant: as long as the construct is syntactically complete, it **can straddle any number of lines**.

It's important to note that **a single command can involve a *mix* of parsing modes**, such as when you pass a script block to a cmdlet, where the cmdlet parses its arguments in argument mode, but the script block itself is parsed in expression mode (see below).

The official documentation on parsing modes is in the conceptual [`about_Parsing` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1).

---

`ForEach-Object` is a *cmdlet* and therefore parsed in *argument mode*.

Thus, unless you use line continuation, it will not look for arguments on *subsequent* lines, and executing `ForEach-Object` on its own, without arguments, causes it to *prompt* for those of its arguments that are mandatory - the `-Process` script block - which is what you saw.

By contrast, `... | ForEach-Object {` works, despite the script block continuing on subsequent lines, because the script block itself is parsed in *expression* mode, allowing it to be spread across multiple lines, whereas *starting* the script block - the opening `{` - on the same line as `ForEach-Object` is sufficient for `ForEach-Object` to recognize it.

---

An example that contrasts *cmdlet* `ForEach-Object`, parsed in *argument* mode, with the `foreach` *statement*, parsed in *expression mode*<sup>[1]</sup>
:

```bash
# Argument mode 
1, 2 | ForEach-Object { # opening brace must be on same line
  "Element: $_" 
}


# Expression mode
foreach ($el in 1, 2) # expression mode - OK to place opening { on next line
{
  "Element: $el" 
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that, perhaps confusingly, `ForEach-Object` has an *alias* also named `foreach`, which blurs the distinction between the cmdlet and the `foreach` *statement*. It is the situational parsing mode that determines wether `foreach` is interpreted as the alias (and therefore refers to `ForEach-Object`)
or as the statement.</sup>

Comment: Incredibly great information, and not info I was able to google (because I didn't know what to search for).  Thanks much